# startx results in blank screen

Tags: xorg, arch-linux

I just installed Xorg on Arch Linux but when I run startx, I only get a blank screen. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Could you post `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep WW`.  That would tell us why Xorg isn't working.

Comment: Umm.. how do I post these files from the linux console? I don't really know how to access this webpage from arch.

Comment: Oh good point.  You could use a tool like `wgetpaste`.  You can use it like this `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE | wgetpaste`  Then it should give you a url to Pastebin.com and you can access that from a computer with a working GUI.

Comment: Or save the output to a file and open it with a working installation, or take a photo and type the text back :)

Comment: wgetpaste isn't working. Download just stalls. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Still couldn't get the whole file but I think here might be the problem-
[94.250] Failed to load module "intel"
[94.264] Failed to load module "fbdev"

Comment: And on the other file (WW)-
Unable to estimate virtual size.
No valid modes left.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? Can you paste here the output of of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE && cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep WW` on your post. Also, where do you get the above `Failed to load module` message?

Comment: Or, to make the command line less confusing (and remove the useless use of `cat`) just run:
`egrep 'EE|WW' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: Are all relevant packages installed? Have you tried installing one of the desktop metapackages, like "xfce4"?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually normal if you do not have a `xinitrc` with a command to start a window manager (or any GUI app). You can also tell startx what it should run directly from the command line:

```
startx `which xterm`
```

will start an Xorg session with an xterm window. you can run stuff from it if you want :) But better install and use a *window manager*.